# Still no aufio Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, speakers, headset

The audio on my computer doesn't work at all. It's not like you hear poorly. There is no audio at all. If I connect external bluetooth headset I can hear everything. I asked the same question a while ago, but without any result. https://askubuntu.com/posts/1482036/revisions

Can anybody help me?